# Accidentally deleted laravel.log from Laravel 8; now, the engine wouldn't populate the it with error messages

Tags: laravel

I wanted to free up the space stored in laravel.log under storage\logs. But when I did, it stopped working, and so I manually removed the laravel.log into the trash bin hoping that laravel would generate a new log file, but it didn't. So, I created a new laravel.log manually. I ran php artisan config:cache and php artisan view:clear to help solve this issue.

Without having to reinstall the whole thing, are there ways to fix this?

Comment: Deleting log files shouldn't cause your entire project to stop working. Do you have an error message you can add to your question to give us a bit more help?

Comment: Tony, I don't disagree that it would break the entire project; the application itself is working fine to clarify. The problem is that nothing is being written to laravel.log, and I'm not sure why. I've tried to open it in Notepad and delete the content. I've tried to open the File Explorer and delete the file. My final attempt was to 'New File' and rename it to 'laravel.log'.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for the clarification. Did you add code to your project to write to the log, what were you expecting to see in the log file? Are you sure the logging code is being called? Try debugging the code by single-stepping through the part where the log is written to, what happens?

Comment: This could be as a result of permission issue. Try to set 775  to storage , and chown

Comment: @EmekaMbah - The OP did say a log file had been created before, so unless the folder has been modified since I don't think this is a permissions issue but worth checking I guess.

Comment: Never mind, it is fixed. :-) I had to force an error to enable laravel to write anything at all. All valid responses, I must say. Thanks for your time and I appreciate the effort.

Comment: @DukeLee - glad to hear you found a solution. Please close/delete, or when you can, answer your own question and accept the answer, so this does not show up as an unanswered question for ever more ;)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve in Windows 10:

Navigate to your project directory, to storage\logs and create a file called laravel.log

Then run php artisan view:clear and php artisan config:cache

Answer (score 0):

deleting `storage/logs/laravel.log` shouldn't create any issue, you can recreate the file by the name of `laravel.log` then add permission to the log file (in ubuntu) by running `sudo chmod -R a+rwx /var/www/html/appplication-name/storage/logs` and then run `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan config:cache`.